# Как передвигать объекты в canvas tkinter мышкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как передвигать объекты в canvas tkinter python3?

Я пробовал функцию move, но она не подходит, так как мне нужно передвигать объекты по заданным координатам.

Comment: Добавьте минимальный пример в вопрос. А передвигать как? Мышкой, клавиатурой, по таймеру, т.е. программно?

Comment: Программно - Мышкой т. е. координаторы задаются программой по оси y и мышкой по оси  x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для перемещения фигур на canvas по координатам используйте метод coords.

Пример (по клику по canvas перемещаем круг):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

shape_id = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 100, 100)

def move_oval(event):
    canvas.coords(shape_id, event.x - 50, event.y - 50, event.x + 50, event.y + 50)

canvas.bind('<1>', move_oval)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но вместо <1> можно вставить зажатие клавиши мыши? т. е. Пока мы держым нажатой кнопку мыши то оно передвигается за указателем мыши.

Comment: @Gleb, можно заменить на `<B1-Motion>` (см. [Events and bindings](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)), но тогда еще нужно сделать проверку, что нажатие произошло в пределах объекта. Если объектов на canvas несколько, то можно воспользоваться методом [find_overlapping](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method) (например, можно найти объекты, пересекающиеся с прямоугольником вокруг курсора), и найденный объект уже двигать.

Answer (score 3):

Положение объектов на Canvas (на холсте) задаётся в координатах. Эти координаты хранятся в самих объектах, созданных на холсте. Чтобы передвинуть объект, его нужно перерисовать в новом месте. Для этого нужно просто изменить его координаты. Для этого есть метод coords(). Нужно передать в него новые координаты объекта.

Одни объекты имеют простую координату x,y (такие как например Text). Но некоторые объекты могут иметь и более сложное обозначение в пространстве. Например, при создании овала нужно передать: (левая_граница_по_x, нижняя_граница_по_y, правая граница_по_x, верхняя граница_по_y).

```
oval = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 100, 100, fill='white')
```

При передвижении объекта нужно передавать тот же тип координат, что при создании, но уже для нового места, куда мы передвинули объект. Для этого нужно взять координаты положения указателя на холсте и на их основе указать новые координаты объекта в метод coords().

```
canvas.coords(oval, x, y, x, y)
```

---

Чтобы это сделать мы используем метод tag_bind(). В него мы передадим:

**имя_объекта** который мы передвигаем;

**событие** (действие которое совершает пользователь и на которое реагирует наша программа);

и **действие** которое программа должна совершить на событие совершённое пользователем.

Делается это вот так: 
имя_экземпляра_класса_Canvas.tag_bind(имя_объекта, событие, действие).

```
canvas.tag_bind(oval, '<B1-Motion>', move_oval)
```

*Метод bind() реагирует на событие на всём холсте. Если использовать его, то привязать событие к конкретному объекту не получится. Регистрироваться событие будет на всей площади холста.*

[Вот здесь перечислены возможные события, совершаемые пользователем](http://ilnurgi1.ru/docs/python/modules/tkinter/base.html)

*На месте "действия" лучше передавать функцию или метод. (Я приведу пример с функцией) Делать это лучше через lambda. Благодаря этому действие будет совершаться не сразу при запуске программы, а лишь тогда, когда пользователь совершит "событие" и метод coords() полноценно сработает, запустив "действие" через lambda.*

```
canvas.tag_bind(oval, '<B1-Motion>', lambda :move_oval)
```

Метод coords() передаёт в функцию "действия" координаты объекта в виде аргумента. Чтобы перехватить эти координаты, нужно в своей функции предусмотреть аргумент. *Рекомендуется давать ему имя event*

В event'е хранятся координаты указателя в момент события. Мы достаём их и на их основе генерируем координаты для нашего объекта, с учётом его размеров.

```
def move_oval(event):
    canvas.coords(oval, event.x - 50, event.y - 50, event.x + 50, event.y + 50)
```

---

Вот, что получается:

```
# Импортируем ткинтер
from tkinter import *

# Создаём окно
root = Tk()

# Создаём и размещаем холст
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

# Создаём объект овал на холсте
# if the oval is not filled, then only the line (border) is considered its body
# Если овал не заполнен, то лишь линия (граница) считается его телом
oval = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 100, 100, fill='white')

# Описываем в функции действие, которое будет происходить при событии, совершаемом пользователем.
# А именно - берём координаты указателя мыши из event, и на их основе 
# генерируем новые координаты, по которым будет перерисовываться овал.
def move_oval(event):
    canvas.coords(oval, event.x - 50, event.y - 50, event.x + 50, event.y + 50)

# Связываем объект на холсте с "событием" и "действием"
canvas.tag_bind(oval, '<B1-Motion>', lambda :move_oval)

# Запускаем цикл исполнения
root.mainloop()
```